# How to retrieve the not common values from 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have the 2 following tables t1, t2 with values,

```
t1        t2
1         4
2         2
3         3
```

Now I want to output

```
1 
4
```

How can I get this output in select query ?

Comment: t1 and t2 are columns??? Or columns of the same table or different tables? Tables don't have values.

Comment: t1, t2 are table names and column names also

Comment: why tagged mysql *and* sql-server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way. Just COUNT them.

This works if the values are unique per table

```
SELECT
    CombinedValue
FROM
    (
    SELECT t1 AS CombinedValue FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2 FROM t2
    ) foo
GROUP BY
    CombinedValue
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1
```

If not unique per table

```
SELECT
    CombinedValue
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1 AS CombinedValue FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT t2 FROM t2
    ) foo
GROUP BY
    CombinedValue
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

This will get you each item from `t1` that is not present in `t2`, and each item in `t2` that is not present in `t1`:

```
select t1.id from t1
left join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where t2.id is null

union all

select t2.id from t2
left join t1 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.id is null
```

(I have assumed that the field name in each table is named `id` just for the sake of being able to write a query against the tables.)

Another way would be:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id)
from t1
full outer join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where t1.id is null or t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Joins in MySql to proceed and to obtain result.

this will help you
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/sql-basics-query-multiple-tables/1050307